# Can YAML Pipeline detect cloud vs Self-Hosted build?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is it possible to determine within a single YAML Pipeline whether the agent is running self-hosted or in a cloud build?  If so, how would one go about determining that?

I need my pipeline to work in both locations but certain steps must only occur if I'm building on one or the other.

Comment: Thank you Leo.  I've have no time the past 2 days to do anything but comment out steps.  Now that I am able to return to this, I think I am going to go with Bartosz agent-variable approach.  That appears to align most closely with what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find directly solution, but it could be done using [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops) and [agent variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables).

For example I have `Hosted Agent` in my agents pool:

[image]

And in YAML I can use this name to condition running step depents on it:

```yaml
steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  condition: eq(variables['Agent.Name'],'Hosted Agent') 
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to determine within a single YAML Pipeline whether the agent is running self-hosted or in a cloud build? If so, how would one go about determining that?

In the YAML Pipeline, there is `pool` keyword, which pool to use for a job of the pipeline.

So, we could use this `pool` keyword to determine within a single YAML Pipeline whether the agent is running self-hosted or in a cloud build:

If you use a self-Hosted agent:

```
pool:
  name: string  # name of the pool to run this job in
```

If you use a Hosted agent:

```
pool:
  vmImage: string # name of the VM image you want to use; valid only in the Microsoft-hosted pool
```

And check [available virtual machine image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent) for some more details.

Besides, if we do not add the `pool` keyword, Azure pipeline will use the default agent. You could check and change it from the `More action` -> Triggers-> YAML of pipeline:

[image]
[image]

> I need my pipeline to work in both locations but certain steps must
> only occur if I'm building on one or the other

Just as Bartosz answered, we could use the condition with [Agent variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables) to achieve this request.